# Silverlight combobox SelectedIndex not changing on binding

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my Silverlight 3.0 application, I have a combobox in my datagrid that binds to a class.
When I change the combobox, I can get the Index to the class, But the combobox doesn't change when I update the class programmatically.

```
<data:datagridtemplatecolumn header="Sale Unit" width="80" xmlns:data="#unknown">
<data:datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate>
<datatemplate>
<combobox itemspanel="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" datacontext="{Binding}" selectedindex="{Binding Path=cursunit,Mode=TwoWay}" keydown="ComboBox_KeyDown" loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" selectionchanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
<comboboxitem content="BOX" />
<comboboxitem content="STRIP" />
<comboboxitem content="PEICE" />
</combobox>
</datatemplate>
</data:datagridtemplatecolumn.celleditingtemplate>
</data:datagridtemplatecolumn>
```

Comment: How dows your cursunit class look?

Answer (score 0):

The path that you are binding the selected index to, does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged and trigger property changed? If it doesn't that could be the problem.